# NLTK Python error at running

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, anaconda, nltk

I have installed the `nltk` in `anaconda` and tried some examples in this tutorial set [pythonprogramming.net](https://pythonprogramming.net/tokenizing-words-sentences-nltk-tutorial/)

After running the [Classifier saving example](https://pythonprogramming.net/pickle-classifier-save-nltk-tutorial/?completed=/naive-bayes-classifier-nltk-tutorial/)  it is showing some errors at the `anaconda` console as follows:

```
(C:\Users\Public\Anaconda) C:\Users\Kalanka PC>pickle.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kalanka PC\pickle.py", line 1, in <module>
    import nltk
  File "C:\Users\Public\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\nltk\__init__.py", line 114, in <module>
    from nltk.collocations import *
  File "C:\Users\Public\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\nltk\collocations.py", line 39, in <module>
    from nltk.metrics import ContingencyMeasures, BigramAssocMeasures, TrigramAssocMeasures
  File "C:\Users\Public\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\nltk\metrics\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from nltk.metrics.segmentation    import windowdiff, ghd, pk
  File "C:\Users\Public\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\nltk\metrics\segmentation.py", line 45, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\Public\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Users\Public\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Users\Public\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\Users\Public\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Users\Public\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    from . import numeric
  File "C:\Users\Public\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 37, in <module>
    import pickle
  File "C:\Users\Kalanka PC\pickle.py", line 4, in <module>
    from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews
  File "C:\Users\Public\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
    from nltk.corpus.reader import *
  File "C:\Users\Public\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
    from nltk.corpus.reader.tagged import *
  File "C:\Users\Public\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\nltk\corpus\reader\tagged.py", line 18, in <module>
    from nltk.tag import str2tuple, map_tag
  File "C:\Users\Public\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
    from nltk.tag.sequential    import (SequentialBackoffTagger, ContextTagger,
  File "C:\Users\Public\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\sequential.py", line 26, in <module>
    from nltk.classify import NaiveBayesClassifier
  File "C:\Users\Public\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\nltk\classify\__init__.py", line 93, in <module>
    from nltk.classify.scikitlearn import SklearnClassifier
  File "C:\Users\Public\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\nltk\classify\scikitlearn.py", line 42, in <module>
    from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
  File "C:\Users\Public\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "C:\Users\Public\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 10, in <module>
    from scipy import sparse
  File "C:\Users\Public\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py", line 70, in <module>
    from numpy.random import rand, randn
  File "C:\Users\Public\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\random\__init__.py", line 99, in <module>
    from .mtrand import *
  File "numpy.pxd", line 86, in init mtrand (numpy\random\mtrand\mtrand.c:42488)
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'dtype'
```

when I try to install it again it shows as follows:

```
C:\Users\Kalanka PC>pip install nltk
Requirement already satisfied:   nltk  
in c:\users\public\anaconda\lib\site-packages Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\public\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from nltk)
```

Comment: On windows, please see https://gist.github.com/alvations/0ed8641d7d2e1941b9f9

Comment: Try changing the name of your file, which is `pickle.py` to another name. And also whether there are 2 versions of python installed.

Answer (score 0):

You may be have saved the file with the name of pickle.py, as it tries to import your pickle file rather than the standard pickle in the module.

I had a similar problem while using pickle, I saved the code file with the name pickle. then when I execute it look for the file you created not the Standard module pickle

Answer (score 0):

Here the naming of the python file is same as the pickle.so it will confuse in loading the related files.
Ex:
the file name is `pickle.py`
 and the code is as follows:

```
`import nltk` 
`import random`
`import pickle`
```